# Windows 7 Computer - BSOD and restart

Tags: windows, bsod

My computer randomly crashes and receives a BSOD.  The BSOD is IRQL_IS_LESS_OR_EQUAL

I checked the event viewer and I'm seeing the following error:

```
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x00000116 (0xfffffa800e66c4e0, 0xfffff8801076d5b0, 0xffffffffc000009a, 0x0000000000000004). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 082710-12105-01.
```

As well as: The previous system shutdown at 12:44:38 PM on ‎8/‎27/‎2010 was unexpected.

And under "Application" in event viewer..I'm seeing errors of the Bonjour Service...

that say: "Task Scheduling Error: m->NextScheduledSPRetry 2013" for example.  But those are at different times from the crash, so not sure if they are related.

What can I do to know what's the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRQL_IS_LESS_OR_EQUAL is almost always caused by a buggy driver. Try updating every driver you can find from the manufacturer.

Comment: i built the computer so i guess i have to update every driver of every piece of hardware on my computer then.  i started with the graphic card...i'll do the MB next.

Comment: You can try downloading the Debugging Tools for Windows and analyzing one of the crash dumps.  It's usually pretty good at catching the driver that caused it.
You can grab it here.
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx